# Will @async scripts ever run before their tags are encountered by the parser?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, asynchronous

Here's what I mean. Take the following example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head><title>test page</title></head>
  <body>
     Will this always be the first thing on the screen every time?
     <script>document.write('Will this be 2nd?');</script>
     <script async src="http://foo.bar/baz.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

...where `baz.js` consists of the following:

```
var s = document.createElement('span');
s.innerHTML = 'Is there any possibility that this will be the first thing to appear on the screen whatsoever, like it\'s being loaded over a really badass fiber optic connection?';
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

I ask because my script depends on a `body` element already existing on the page for me to append to, but I'm not controlling where on the page my markup gets inserted other than the fact that I know it will be somewhere in the body.  **Are there browsers that do a scan over the markup for `async` and `defer` scripts before they begin their main round of parsing to see if there's anything they should start downloading beforehand?**

Let me know if the question isn't clear enough and I'll try to clarify.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `script` elements are not acted upon until the parser reaches them.

Your `"Will this be 2nd?"` script will always run before the other one.

In both cases, you can rely on `document.body`.

[More reading](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-script-element.html#attr-script-async) on the full details of `async` and `defer`.